# Renaming package in goclipse causes problems

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I use Eclipse as IDE for Go (I guess it's called "Goclipse"), developing a web application. All went good and nice until I started to split functionality in smaller packages. Initially I had a package `gitserver/user/project/portal`. File `main.go` imported it and everything was working. I suddenly realized, that it should be called `gitserver/user/project/webserver` instead, and some other files and functionality should go into `.../portal`. So I did "Rename", by right clicking in Project Explorer.

main.go:

```golang
package main
import(
  "gitserver/user/project/webserver"
)

func main(){
  webserver.DoSomeStuff()
}
```

Compiler complains that

- imported and not used "gitserver/user/project/webserver" as portal
- undefined: webserver

[...]

How to untie the "webserver" package from its old name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoClipse doesn't actually do any tracking of the old name after the rename is done. Based on what you describe and the error `imported and not used "gitserver/user/project/webserver" as portal` you probably have an `import` line along the lines of `portal "gitserver/user/project/webserver"` somewhere, and probably in the same file it uses `webserver.`. Double check all your imports because these errors absolutely sound like the rename just got a little mixed up (something that's not uncommon when doing a rename and reusing the old name).

Goclipse may not find every kind of reference to the package when renaming; the change might not be cascaded throughout the project, or even the package files. When you rename a folder, check that the `package` line has been changed in the package files, and update them if not.

Comment: Marked as accepted answer because of  "Double check all your...". I did the double check, triple check and finally found my mistake.